# Rspec trace repeats context multiple times?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've been noticing a bug in my rspec output lately, specifically in the full description for failed specs - it always doubled the context when it ended the output early, but lately it's been doing more than doubling and in situations where the run wasn't cancelled early.

As an example:

> 1. In the 'accounts' area when the user type is 'admin' In the 'accounts' area when the user type is 'admin' on the "user details"
>      page In the 'accounts' area when the user type is 'admin' In the
>      'accounts' area when the user type is 'admin' on the "user details"
>      page behaves like a page with an Accounts Menu In the 'accounts' area
>      when the user type is 'admin' In the 'accounts' area when the user
>      type is 'admin' on the "user details" page In the 'accounts' area when
>      the user type is 'admin' In the 'accounts' area when the user type is
>      'admin' on the "user details" page behaves like a page with an
>      Accounts Menu there should be a link called 'Home'
>
> Failure/Error: ::error message here::

What could be causing this, and how can I stop it?

Further details:
It seems to occur most often with shared example groups. ESPECIALLY shared example groups that use other shared example groups.

Here is a rough, stripped down example of the kind of code I'm using.:

```
shared_examples "a page with a standard page header" do
 before(:each){ @header=find(:xpath,"//*[@id='page_header']") }
 it_behaves_like "a header with a user control menu"
 context "the standard menu" do
   test "should exist"
 end
end

shared_examples "a page with an administrative header" do
 before(:each){ @header=find(:xpath,"//*[@id='page_header']") }
 it_behaves_like "a header with a user control menu"
 context "the admin menu" do
  test "should exist"
 end
end

shared_examples "a header with a user control menu" do
 context "the user control menu" do
  test "should exist"
 end
end

users_type.each do |user|
 describe "/index" do
  before(:each){ @user=set_up_user(user);login_as(@user); visit(page)}
  context "when the user is a #{user.type}" do
   if(['general','mod'].includes?(@user.type))
    test "some things should be true"
    it_behaves_like "a page with a standard page header"
   elsif('admin'==@user.type)
    test "some other things should be true"
    it_behaves_like "a page with an administrative header"
   else
    it_behaves_like "access denied"
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Supplying your rspec code may help.

Comment: Its actually happened across several examples, and seldom repeats twice and rarely in the same exact manner. I have noticed it tends to happen with shared groups, though. The actual code isn't something I can provide.

Comment: +1, because we're seeing this with a nested shared example group too and have just ignored it until now.

Comment: We really need to see a test case. If it's a common problem, it should be easy to reproduce, no?

Comment: I've put forward an example that is similar in structure to the tests I'm running, since I'm sure you don't want several pages of example. Some of the context may obviously be missing.